# Matplotlib imshow low quality compared to OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matplotlib

I am doing some computer vision with python so I am using both opencv and matplotlib. I want to switch to matplotlib for viewing images but I found that the image quality is low compared to OpenCV `imshow` also the images are not shown with right size on screen they are all the same size.

This is how I use to

```
img = cv2.imread('a.png',0)
f = plt.figure(figsize=(img.shape[1],img.shape[0]), dpi=1)
plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
plt.axis('false')
plt.imshow(img,cmap="gray",interpolation=None)
```

I tried with different values for interpolation but still the quality is very low compared to opencv is there to show image with better quality?

Also when printing I get same low quality not like the opencv write method.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the figure size too large. [img.shape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) returns the number of rows and columns in img but [figsize](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) uses inches.

Also, you probably want the figure to have a different resolution than dpi = 1. Dots per inch should be more like 80 and may need to be higher depending on how you'll display the image.

Comment: Well `dpi = 1` will make 1 pixel per inch so I can use image pixels for figure size, as now pixels = inches so at least when I am showing the image I dont think the dpi has anything to do with the quality of the image (maybe text written on axis etc..). Anyway I found that making `interpolation='none'` not `None` the quality is much better. And I can bypass the `dpi=1` thing by using `figaspect(img)` to get inches according to image size for current dpi and in the same time I  can still have the text appear correctly.